# Avoid sort on last row in the table DataTable plugin

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

```
var oTable = $('#table').dataTable({
                "sScrollX": "100%",
                "sScrollXInner": "150%",
                "bScrollCollapse": true,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bSortable": true          
            });
            new FixedColumns(oTable, {
                "iLeftColumns": 1,
                "iRightColumns": 1
            });
```

I am using data table plugin, And my initialize code is as above, i want my last row not column not to be sorted, when i click on any header. I searched every where I couldn't find a way to stop row sorting...Please help me out..............

Answer (score 10):

The HTML needs to have a specific setup with thead and tbody tags.
So theoretically I could put my last row into a tfoot tag and it wouldn't be affected by sorting.

hope this will work for you.

http://blog.adrianlawley.com/tablesorter-jquery-how-to-exclude-rows/

Comment: I am using datatable, not tablesorter

Comment: When i add fixed columns one on right and right they will mess up

Comment: Just to know is it possible to have the row in body instead of footer

Comment: That was the perfect solution for my case. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Add Footer To The Table .... It Wont Sort The Last Column

```html
<tfoot>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><b>TOTAL</b></td>
      <td id="billedAmount"></td>
      <td id="totalOtherCharges"></td>
      <td id="totalCost"></td>
   </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Answer (score 0):

Placing lat row in 'tfoot' tags will sort you out just fine. Worked for me